# Injective Lie Group Homomorphism, compact domain

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Problem:

Assume $F:G\rightarrow G$ is an injective Lie group homomorphism, where $G$ is finite dimensional. If $G$ is compact, then show that $F$ is surjective.

**Incomplete attempt:**

As $F$ is a Lie group homomorphism, it has constant rank. Hence, the differential $F_{*,e}:\mathfrak{g}\rightarrow \mathfrak{g}$ is an isomorphism. Hence by the Inverse function theorem, $F$ is a local diffeomorphism.
Since $G$ is compact, $F$ is closed. Since $F$ is a local diffeomorphism, $F$ is open.
Moreover, $F:G\rightarrow F(G)$ is a homeomorphism, and so $F(G_0)=G_0$ since $G_0$ is the only open connected subgroup of $G$.

Now why does it follow that $F$ is surjective?

Comment: The map maps the connected component $G_0$ of $1$ into itself, so you can consider the induced map on $G/G_0$. If it is not surjective, it is not injective, as the quotient is finite, and thus there are at least two connected components of $G$ mapped into $G_0$. Your argument shows that the restiction of $f$ to each of those components is a diffeo onto $G_0$, and this contradicts injectivity.

Comment: I don't think you have "improved the quality of your question" by removing your original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $G$ is compact, it has a finite number of connected components, and one can write
$$
G=\bigsqcup_{i=0}^{n-1} G_i,
$$
where each $G_i$ is a connected component and $G_0$ is that of the neutral element.
For each $i$, pick $g_i\in G_i$.
Then $G_i = g_i G_0$.
Since $F$ is a group homomorphism,
$$
F(G_i) = F(g_i)F(G_0) = F(g_i)G_0.
$$
Let $i,j\in \{0,\ldots,n-1\}$, and assume that $F(g_i)G_0 = F(g_j)G_0$.
Then $F(g_j^{-1}g_i)G_0 = G_0$, which yields $F(g_j^{-1}g_i)\in G_0$.
By injectivity of $F$, and since $F(G_0)=G_0$, it follows that $g_j^{-1}g_i \in G_0$.
Therefore, $g_i$ and $g_j$ are in the same connected component, and $g_i=g_j$.
It follows that $F(G_k)$ are pairwise disjoint, from which is deduced the surjectivity of $F$.